# How can i use an existing existing chrome browser instance in selenium C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

How do I use an existing chrome browser in selenium C# ?

Currently I have the following but it always creates a new window

```
SessionId sessionId = new SessionId("");
var driver = new phantomJSDriver();
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

Comment: why is driver declared twice?

Comment: WebDriver always creates a new browser, one that is fresh, so you are certain of the state. I would say most people will want to start with a known fresh state before they start executing tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34675/how-to-reuse-existing-browser-session-instead-of-opening-new-windows

Comment: Specifying _why_ you want to use an existing window may yield better answers/reframes. [In past projects I've _launched_ the webdriver through Python in an Interactive Mode for a mix of manual and automated testing, but without context I can't be confident if that might be a remotely viable answer for your use-case]